# How to keep Java 32 and 64 Bit at the same version?

Tags: java, windows-7, 64-bit

can anybody please explain to me how I can keep Java 64Bit and 32Bit at the same Patchlevel on my Win7 x64 machine? The java updater is really a disappointment, and it does not even tell you which version it is actually updatinmg, all it is good for is trying to get you new adware (toolbars) installed, really a pain :(

Nevertheless, this is what my system looks like at the moment, and the java updater installed tells me everything is okay:

[image]

How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

1. My recommendation is to standardize the Java version and use one
   version - ideally the 64-bit; Unless there's a valid reason behind it.
2. After standardizing I would try to update Java again.
3. If this still doesn't work you can try to re-install.